# Identify if the position of a value changes relative to it's previous association

Tags: r, dataframe, logical-operators

I have a data frame of data grouped by `site` and `deploy.id`. Within each site, `deploy.id` is arranged chronologically and identifies the direction (`bearing`) of each antenna (`ant`) during that equipment deployment. The column `lag` shows the bearing of each `ant` in the previous deployment. In my dataset, the number of antennas within a deployment can range from one to ten. I have generated columns that identify if, within each site, the antenna angle of each antenna number is the same as the previous deployment and what the `deploy.id' of the the previous deployment was.

```
site = c(rep(1,6),rep(2,9))
deploy.id = c(rep(657,3), rep(755,3), rep(2029,3), rep(2107,3), rep(3732,3))
date = c("2014-04-25", "2014-04-25", "2014-04-25", "2014-08-11", "2014-08-11", "2014-08-11","2014-11-21", "2014-11-21", "2014-11-21", "2015-04-02","2015-04-02","2015-04-02","2016-11-22", "2016-11-22","2017-04-27")
port = c(rep(1:3,5))
bearing = c(0,120,240,90,60,360,90,60,120,90,60,120,90,120,60)
same.angle = c(rep(NA,3), rep(F,3), rep(NA,3), rep(T,3),T,F,F)
lag = c(rep(NA,3),0,120,240, rep(NA,3),90,60,120,90,60,120)
prev.deploy.id = c(rep(NA,3), rep(657,3), rep(NA,3), rep(755,3), rep(2029,3))
df <- data.frame(site, deploy.id, port, date, bearing, lag, same.angle, prev.deploy.id)

df

   site deploy.id  ant       date bearing lag same.angle prev.deploy.id
1     1       657    1 2014-04-25       0  NA         NA             NA
2     1       657    2 2014-04-25     120  NA         NA             NA
3     1       657    3 2014-04-25     240  NA         NA             NA
4     1       755    1 2014-08-11      90   0      FALSE            657
5     1       755    2 2014-08-11      60 120      FALSE            657
6     1       755    3 2014-08-11     360 240      FALSE            657
7     2      2029    1 2014-11-21      90  NA         NA             NA
8     2      2029    2 2014-11-21      60  NA         NA             NA
9     2      2029    3 2014-11-21     120  NA         NA             NA
10    2      2107    1 2015-04-02      90  90       TRUE            755
11    2      2107    2 2015-04-02      60  60       TRUE            755
12    2      2107    3 2015-04-02     120 120       TRUE            755
13    2      3732    1 2016-11-22      90  90       TRUE           2029
14    2      3732    2 2016-11-22     120  60      FALSE           2029
15    2      3732    3 2017-04-27      60 120      FALSE           2029
```

Based on the previous deployment within each site, I want to generate a new column indicating if the `bearing` of a given `ant` was associated with a different `ant` number in the previous deployment. Specifically, I want to know when both `ant` `bearing` are switched (eg. `ant` 2 WAS at 60 degrees but is now at 120 while `ant` 3 was 120 but is now at 60 degrees). Ex.

```
site = c(rep(1,6),rep(2,9))
deploy.id = c(rep(657,3), rep(755,3), rep(2029,3), rep(2107,3), rep(3732,3))
date = c("2014-04-25", "2014-04-25", "2014-04-25", "2014-08-11", "2014-08-11", "2014-08-11","2014-11-21", "2014-11-21", "2014-11-21", "2015-04-02","2015-04-02","2015-04-02","2016-11-22", "2016-11-22","2017-04-27")
port = c(rep(1:3,5))
bearing = c(0,120,240,90,60,360,90,60,120,90,60,120,90,120,60)
same.angle = c(rep(NA,3), rep(F,3), rep(NA,3), rep(T,3),T,F,F)
lag = c(rep(NA,3),0,120,240, rep(NA,3),90,60,120,90,60,120)
prev.deploy.id = c(rep(NA,3), rep(657,3), rep(NA,3), rep(755,3), rep(2029,3))
switched = c(rep(F,13), T, T)
df = data.frame(site, deploy.id, port, date, bearing, lag, same.angle, prev.deploy.id, switched)

df

   site deploy.id  ant       date bearing lag same.angle prev.deploy.id switched
1     1       657    1 2014-04-25       0  NA         NA             NA    FALSE
2     1       657    2 2014-04-25     120  NA         NA             NA    FALSE
3     1       657    3 2014-04-25     240  NA         NA             NA    FALSE
4     1       755    1 2014-08-11      90   0      FALSE            657    FALSE
5     1       755    2 2014-08-11      60 120      FALSE            657    FALSE
6     1       755    3 2014-08-11     360 240      FALSE            657    FALSE
7     2      2029    1 2014-11-21      90  NA         NA             NA    FALSE
8     2      2029    2 2014-11-21      60  NA         NA             NA    FALSE
9     2      2029    3 2014-11-21     120  NA         NA             NA    FALSE
10    2      2107    1 2015-04-02      90  90       TRUE            755    FALSE
11    2      2107    2 2015-04-02      60  60       TRUE            755    FALSE
12    2      2107    3 2015-04-02     120 120       TRUE            755    FALSE
13    2      3732    1 2016-11-22      90  90       TRUE           2029    FALSE
14    2      3732    2 2016-11-22     120  60      FALSE           2029     TRUE
15    2      3732    3 2017-04-27      60 120      FALSE           2029     TRUE
```

I've tried using a few combinations of the `group_by()` and the `which()` function to see if I could make a condition based on the position of the bearing but so far, haven't had any luck.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think I have rough idea of what you're looking for, but still uncertain. First can you clarify if `port` is the antenna (`ant`)? Second, for `site` 1 on 2014-08-11, it appears there were changes in `bearing`, from 120 --> 60 (`port` 2) and 240 --> 360 (`port` 3) - should that be counted as `switched`? Third, if just one `port` changes in a deployment, does that count as `switched`?

Comment: One initial thought in looking at this, is to `arrange` (e.g., with `dplyr`) and order by date within a given `site` and `port` (group by both `site` and `port` and not by `deploy.id`). Then, if the dates are in order, you can compare the `bearing` with the previous (`lag`) bearing to detect changes, and see if `switched`.

Comment: Hi @Ben. Thanks for your help.1)  I've edited the post but yes, `port` is the same as `ant`. In my actual dataset `port` represents the antenna. 2) Good question, I hadn't thought of it that way. In the new column, I'm trying to identify instances where the antenna numbers have been logged as the wrong bearing as opposed to instances where the bearing has changed to a new direction. So at `site` 1 in rows 4,5,and 6, the bearings have changed but to directions unlike the previous deployment at that site (rows 1,2,3) so `switched` would be `FALSE`.

Comment: 3) Yes. Ideally if any one `ant` had the same bearing as any other `ant` in a previous deployment, `switched` should be `TRUE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be something worth trying, using the `dplyr` package.

As you want to see if the `bearing` was present in the previous `deploy.id`, and you have the values available in a `lag` column, you're probably close.

Agree with grouping by both `site` and `deploy.id`, since you want to consider all `bearing` values within this specific group.

You can set `switched` to logical `TRUE` if both of the following are `TRUE`:

1. `bearing` is included in `lag` within the group (specific `site` and `deploy.id`). Use `%in%` to see if `bearing` is contained with the vector including all `lag` values. For example, for `deploy.id` 755, 90 is *not* contained within vector c(0, 120, 240). However, for `deploy.id` 3732, 120 *is* contained within vector c(90, 60, 120).
2. The second part is comparing the `bearing` value with the `lag` value in the same row. Here, for `deploy.id` 3732, you have 90 and 90 which are the same, so result is `FALSE`. However, you have 120 != 60 and 60 != 120, so those other two rows would have `TRUE`.

**Code**

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(site, deploy.id) %>%
  mutate(switched = bearing %in% lag & bearing != lag)
```

**Output**

```
    site deploy.id  port date       bearing   lag same.angle prev.deploy.id switched
   <dbl>     <dbl> <int> <chr>        <dbl> <dbl> <lgl>               <dbl> <lgl>   
 1     1       657     1 2014-04-25       0    NA NA                     NA FALSE   
 2     1       657     2 2014-04-25     120    NA NA                     NA FALSE   
 3     1       657     3 2014-04-25     240    NA NA                     NA FALSE   
 4     1       755     1 2014-08-11      90     0 FALSE                 657 FALSE   
 5     1       755     2 2014-08-11      60   120 FALSE                 657 FALSE   
 6     1       755     3 2014-08-11     360   240 FALSE                 657 FALSE   
 7     2      2029     1 2014-11-21      90    NA NA                     NA FALSE   
 8     2      2029     2 2014-11-21      60    NA NA                     NA FALSE   
 9     2      2029     3 2014-11-21     120    NA NA                     NA FALSE   
10     2      2107     1 2015-04-02      90    90 TRUE                  755 FALSE   
11     2      2107     2 2015-04-02      60    60 TRUE                  755 FALSE   
12     2      2107     3 2015-04-02     120   120 TRUE                  755 FALSE   
13     2      3732     1 2016-11-22      90    90 TRUE                 2029 FALSE   
14     2      3732     2 2016-11-22     120    60 FALSE                2029 TRUE    
15     2      3732     3 2017-04-27      60   120 FALSE                2029 TRUE
```